# JButtons keep resizing in the gridBagLayout after adding a border triggered by a mouseEvent

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I have a JPanel split into 3 Cells.
Flure is on on the leftPanel of each cell in each of the 16 Particles.
Flyr is on the rightPanel of each cell in a 4 by 4 grid.

I'm having trouble trying to get my buttons (Flure and Flyr) to not resize whenever I set the border. The border is set whenever the buttons are pressed. I think it has to do with how I'm using the gridBagConstraints, or it could be the size that I'm not setting.

This is what it looks like when the program is launched:
[image]

This is what it looks like when you click on Flure and Flyr:
[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GridBagTest {

    private static JFrame myFrame;
    private static JPanel mainPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createFrame();
        createPanels();
        constructCells();
        myFrame.pack();
        myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createFrame() {
        myFrame = new JFrame();
        myFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        myFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        myFrame.setTitle("Simulator");
        myFrame.setResizable(true);
    }

    private static void createPanels() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        myFrame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    }

    private static void constructCells() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            mainPanel.add(new Cell(i + 1), choosePosition(i + 1));
        }
    }

    private static String choosePosition(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                return BorderLayout.EAST;
            case 2:
                return BorderLayout.CENTER;
            case 3:
                return BorderLayout.WEST;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*; 

class Cell extends JButton {
    private static final int NUMPARTICLES = 16;
    private JPanel leftPanel;
    private JPanel rightPanel;

    public Cell(int number) {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        initFields();
        initParticles();
        initPanels();
        if (number == 1)
            this.setBackground(Color.red);
        if (number == 2)
            this.setBackground(Color.blue);
        if (number == 3)
            this.setBackground(Color.green);
    }
    private void initFields(){
        this.leftPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        this.rightPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    }

    private void initParticles(){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill =  GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        for(int i=0;i<NUMPARTICLES;i++){
            gbc.gridy = i;
            leftPanel.add(new Particle(),gbc);
        }
    }

    private void initPanels(){
        initButtons();
        splitPane();
    }

    private void initButtons(){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill =  GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc.ipadx = 10;
        gbc.ipady = 30;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            gbc.gridx = i+2;
            for(int j=0;j<NUMPARTICLES/4;j++){
                gbc.gridy = j+2;
                rightPanel.add(new Flure(),gbc);
            }
        }
    }

    private void splitPane(){
        JSplitPane sp = new 
        JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,leftPanel,rightPanel);
        sp.setEnabled(false);
        sp.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        this.add(sp);
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;

public class Particle extends JButton {

    public Particle(){
        this.setEnabled(false);
        this.setBackground(Color.gray);
        this.setForeground(Color.white);
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        initButtons();
    }

    private void initButtons(){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        this.add(new Flyr(),gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 1;
        this.add(new Flyr(),gbc);
        gbc.gridx = 2;
        JButton flurSign = new JButton();
        flurSign.setEnabled(false);
        flurSign.setBackground(Color.black);
        flurSign.setBackground(Color.blue);
        this.add(flurSign,gbc);
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Flyr extends JButton implements MouseListener {
    private static final LineBorder LB = new LineBorder(Color.magenta, 3);
    public Flyr(){
        setMargin(new Insets(15,15,15,15));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        setBorder(LB);
    }

}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class Flure extends JButton implements MouseListener {
    private static final LineBorder LB = new LineBorder(Color.green, 3);

    public Flure() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        setText("UP");
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        setBorder(LB);
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting the border changes the size of the buttons

Comment: A substitue idea, might be to place each `JButton` on a `JPanel`, use a `GridBagLayout` with an `Insets` of the desired size to position the button on the panel and simply change the background of the `JPanel`

Comment: Also, a `ActionListener` would be more appropriate then a `MosueListener` for handing buttons

Comment: One problem is that when the JPanel's border is activated, it is covered by the button inside the JPanel. How do I add inner margins for my JPanel so that the buttons won't block the border?

Comment: As I said, use the insets properties the GridBagConstraints to make a fake border